# how to use function_exists() or class_exists() instead of is_plugin_active() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I got an issue with the Envanto Theme Check plugin.

> REQUIRED: Found is_plugin_active( in the file plugin-activation.php. is_plugin_active() is not reliable. Use
>   function_exists() or class_exists() instead.

Line 816 is:

```
if ( $this->is_automatic && ! $this->is_plugin_active( $slug ) )
```

Here is my code:

```
if ( $this->is_automatic && ! $this->is_plugin_active( $slug ) ) {
    $plugin_activate = $upgrader->plugin_info(); 
    if ( false === $this->activate_single_plugin( $plugin_activate, $slug, true ) ) {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: if(!function_exists('your_function_name')) {
function your_function_name(){// I am available}}

Comment: i got u but it doesnot solves my issue

Comment: did you use the action for this or you write code directly to the file?

Comment: their is nothing wrong with the code but the theme forest requirement says is_plugin_active is not reliable. any idea or alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of slug name give a class name in `tgmp.php` and check for `class_exists` in `plugin-activation.php`

**tgmp.php**

```
array(
    'name'      => __('Jetpack', 'slug'),
    'slug'      => 'Jetpack_Autoupdate',
    'required'  => false,
),
```

now in plugin-activation.php check this `$this->class_exists( $slug ) )`